# Cross-application drag-and-drop in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, drag-and-drop, windows-explorer

I would like to create a Delphi application for Windows XP which allows dropping of files dragged from Windows Explorer (the Desktop or folder windows) or other applications which support this operation (such as Total Commander). What about vice-versa? When the user drags an icon from my application, I should be able to set the contents of the dragged object to custom data.

My goal is to create a custom application toolbar, onto which I can drop applications and show their icons or drag applications or other entities from it.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This can be done with [The Drag and Drop Component Suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/). It also has examples for what you want.

Comment: The URL isn't working right now. Could have been stackoverflowed ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashdot_effect ), I'll try again a bit later because it sure sounds interesting!

Comment: It's a very slow server, AFAICT. Probably just ADSL upstream rate.
The Drag and Drop suite is very good, but NOT YET ported for Delphi 2009.

Comment: It looks like the components have been updated to work in Delphi 2010, but not yet Delphi XE2.

Answer (score 3):

[Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing) has a nice series of articles about drag&drop:

- [What a drag Archives | The Old New Thing](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/tag/what-a-drag)
- [What a drag: Dragging a virtual file (HGLOBAL edition)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080318-00/?p=23083)
- [What a drag: Dragging a virtual file (IStorage edition)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080320-00/?p=23063)
- [What a drag: Dragging a virtual file (IStream edition)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080319-00/?p=23073)

There are many other good articles on his blog when you search for drag and drop.