# Delphi 2007 drag from app

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, delphi-2007

this is a general question that I was asked to investigate. 
What would we need, generally speaking, to be able to drag an image file (tif) from our Delphi 2007 application to some other application?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps this link is helpful ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295259/cross-application-drag-and-drop-in-delphi

Comment: I think you need to supply more details. In what form is the tif file in your app. What format do you use when dragging? Tif? Does the other app support tifs being dropped? What is the other app? Do you need help with the dragging itself? I don't really want to spent time helping now because I'm not sure I know what you need and I think it would likely be wasted time.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way would be to use this component: http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/ , which exists since a long time. You have all the components variants for drag and drop: source/target, various source/target kind.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good sample:
[Drag and Drop files from your application to Windows Explorer](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2335)