# Why doesn't my form receive WM_DropFiles when files are dropped on it?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

I am using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE to develop an application. I am trying catch the file(s) drag and drop to the application with the following code

```
TMainForm = class(TForm)
public:
  procedure WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles); message WM_DROPFILES;
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(Self.Handle, True);
end;

procedure TMainForm.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(Self.Handle, False);
end;

procedure TMainForm.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles);
begin
  inherited;
  showmessage('catch here');
  // some code to handle the drop files here
  Msg.Result := 0;
end;
```

This code complied without problem. Also, when I drag and drop files, the cursor show that the status changed to drag and drop but after things dropped, nothing happen (no message shown too). Is that anything wrong with that?

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295259/62576)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a plain vanilla application, the code in the question results in `WMDropFiles` executing when an object is dropped on the form. So, clearly there's something else happening to stop it working. The most obvious potential causes are:

1. The main form's window handle is re-created after the initial call to `DragAcceptFiles`.
2. Your process is running at a higher integrity level than the process that is dropping files on it. For example, are you running your process as administrator. Note that running the Delphi IDE as administrator would lead to your process running as administrator when started from the IDE.
3. Something else in your process is interfering with drag/drop. Without knowing what's in your app, it's hard to guess what this could be. Start removing portions of your app until there's nothing left but the code in the question.

Option 2 seems quite plausible. To learn more see: [Q: Why Doesn’t Drag-and-Drop work when my Application is Running Elevated? – A: Mandatory Integrity Control and UIPI](http://patrickablog.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2010/01/28/q-why-doesnt-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi/)

Comment: Thanks guys. To check option 2, I run notepad and it does open the file while drag and drop. Also, the application was implemented by someone else, the src code is pretty complicated but he uses TForm. I try to create an application with only TForm and use above code, then it works. But I still don't know what cause it doesn't work for the original program.

Comment: I've given you a couple of pointers, but since you have the code to the problem app, only you can persue it.

Comment: @user - Checking option 1 is easy too, call the FormCreate procedure from a button click or the like. BTW I don't understand the relation with notepad, running your application outside the IDE should be enough.

Comment: Thanks Sertac. I check option 1 with your method too. It doesn't work too. Well, the reason I check notepad is to figure out if there is any thing blocked in the windows.

Comment: You can check 2 using Process Explorer. Right click on the list view column header and click "Select Columns". Select "Integrity Level" from the "Process Image" page. Compare the IL of explorer.exe and your process.

Comment: To address #1, override the form's `CreateWnd()` and `DestroyWnd()` methods to call `DragAcceptFiles()`, don't use the `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` events for that. To address #2, use `ChangeWindowMessageFilter/Ex()` to allow `WM_DROPFILES` messages from lower-privileged processes.

Comment: I think I found the reason causing the problem. I tried to copy the program to the C:\ or D:\, the program will be run directly and the drag and drop works. But if I run it from where it was compiled, a user control dialog will be pop up and the drag and drop doesn't work. I run that in windows 7. Why at some folder the user control dialog appears while at somewhere else it doesn't? And how to remove the user control for some specific folder?

Comment: @user - Check compatibility settings of the executable in the output folder.

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted. Especially as it has been confirmed that item 2 was the cause.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Where is the correct place to use ChangeWindowMessageFilter to allow WM_DROPFILES messages from lower-privileged processes? On form create or on CreateWnd()? Is MarcinH solution correct?

Comment: @AlexV see my comment to MarcinH's answer

Comment: Thank you, for me it was option 2 here, I was running my IDE as admin, as soon as I ran the exe outside the IDE everything worked just fine, but when run from inside the IDE as an admin it did not work

Comment: @StevenW you probably should stop running the ide as admin. I've never need to do that. Whatever led you there, there is surely a different solution.

Answer (score 10):

in `TForm.Create` use two lines

```
ChangeWindowMessageFilter (WM_DROPFILES, MSGFLT_ADD);

ChangeWindowMessageFilter (WM_COPYGLOBALDATA, MSGFLT_ADD);
```

that's all

Comment: Can you append some comments on your post (why that should fix the problem)?

Comment: It would be better to use `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` to limit the filter to just the Form's window rather than global for the entire process. In which case, overriding the Form's `CreateWnd()` method would be more appropriate than using the `OnCreate` event, in case the window is ever recreated at runtime.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I could not find `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx` in Delphi. I had to `external 'user32.dll'` it. Did I miss it somewhere?

Comment: @AlexV AFAIK, Delphi's RTL does not expose either `ChangeWindowMessageFilter()` or `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` (unless that has changed in recent versions), you have to declare them manually in your own code.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Yes, `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` is now exposed in `Winapi.Windows` (Delphi 10.4 here).

Comment: @AlexV `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` was introduced in Windows 7, which predates Delphi 10.4 by 11 years.  Embarcadero must really be behind in exposing modern APIs. Oh well, so you have to define an `extern` (and preferably `delayed`) declaration for it, no big deal, it is a simple API to declare. That is one of Delphi''s strengths, being able to use APIs that the RTL doesn't know about natively.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Indeed! I discovered the `delayed` feature today! That's nice to support older versions of Windows! Thanks!