# Drag and Drop files to Delphi form not working

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I've tried to accept files that are dragged and dropped to a Form from the File Explorer but it doesn't work. My WM_DROPFILES handler is never called. I'm running Windows 8 if that makes any difference.

Here's a simple example of what I do (I just have a TMemo on the form):

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Memo1: TMemo;
  private
    { Private declarations }
    procedure WMDROPFILES(var msg : TWMDropFiles) ; message WM_DROPFILES;
    procedure CreateWnd; override;
    procedure DestroyWnd; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, True);

end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  DragAcceptFiles(Handle, false);

end;

procedure TForm1.WMDROPFILES(var msg: TWMDropFiles);
var
  i, fileCount: integer;
  fileName: array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
begin
  fileCount:=DragQueryFile(msg.Drop, $FFFFFFFF, fileName, MAX_PATH);
  for i := 0 to fileCount - 1 do
  begin
    DragQueryFile(msg.Drop, i, fileName, MAX_PATH);
    Memo1.Lines.Add(fileName);
  end;
  DragFinish(msg.Drop);
end;
```

Comment: I've tested your code and it works. Windows 7, Delphi XE. I only swapped lines in `DestroyWnd` but it should not matter - it works as expected.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482304/why-doesnt-my-form-receive-wm-dropfiles-when-files-are-dropped-on-it

Comment: @Serg: the order in `DestroyWnd()` does matter. `DragAcceptFiles()` needs to be called before `inherited`, because `inherited` will actually destroy the `HWND`. The next time the `Handle` is read after being destroyed, a new `HWND` is created via `CreateWnd()`. If the order is backwards, the end result will be that `DragAcceptFiles(FALSE)` gets called last, disabling Drag&Drop.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Most likely you are running your application elevated. Probably because you are running Delphi elevated. In Vista and later, low privilege processes cannot send messages to higher privilege processes. This [MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/01/28/q-why-doesn-t-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi.aspx) explains more.

If you are running your Delphi IDE elevated, I urge you to stop doing so. There's very seldom a need to do so for standard desktop application development.

---

As Remy points out, your `DestroyWnd` is incorrect. You are destroying the window handle before calling `DragAcceptFiles`. Simply reverse the order. Personally I'd use `WindowHandle` in both `CreateWnd` and `DestroyWnd`. The `Handle` property creates the window handle if it is not assigned and so masks such errors.

```
procedure TForm1.CreateWnd;
begin
  inherited;
  DragAcceptFiles(WindowHandle, True);
end;

procedure TForm1.DestroyWnd;
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(WindowHandle, false);
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: That was probably it. Thanks buddy :)